# User defined function creation with case statement

Tags: sql, case, user-defined-functions

I was told to create a function to find the closest opening business hours. Say it is after 5 pm Friday now, it should return me Monday 8 am. If it was Wednesday 6pm, it should return me Thursday 8 am.

````
returns datetime as
begin
Declare @dayStart datetime = cast(cast(@date as date) as datetime)
Declare @startbusinesshour datetime = dateadd(hh, 8, @daystart)
Declare @endbusinesshour datetime = dateadd(hh, 18, @daystart)
return
case 
when @date < @startbusinesshour  then @date = @startbusinesshour
when @date>@endbusinesshour then @date=dateadd(day, 1, @startbusinesshour )
when DATENAME(dw, @date)='Saturday' then @date=dateadd(day, 2, @date)
when DATENAME(dw, @date)='Sunday' then @date=dateadd(day, 1, @date)
else retun @date
end```
````

Comment: Please provide sample data and tag with the database you are using.

Comment: If it's Wednesday at 2PM, should it still return Thursday at 8AM, or Wednesday at 8AM as we are still within business hours?